# My scikit learn machine learning kivy app crashes on android every time i try to run it can any one help me?

Tags: kivy

I have made a small kivy android app and run it on android using kivy launcher and all the buttons works fine without giving single error. But when I try to link my scikit learn machine learning model to a particular button then it starts to crash on android. I have my decision tree model that works fine with out any error and I saved it using pickel and the I loaded the saved model to my kivy app but it crashes when I try to run it on android using kivy launcher and also when I make the apk of this app it crashes too.

```
import pickle
```

`model = pickle.load(open("prediction_model.sav", 'rb'))`

```
def result(d):
value=model._predict(d)
if(value == 1):
return "your test is positive "
else:
return "your test is negative "



                                                                                                                 when I add these lines where my model make prediction on a particular data and it work fine when I run it on pycharm it dose not show any error and the same code crashes when I try to run it on android kivy launcher
```

Comment: Can you provide any code for what you have so far?

Comment: import pickle

model = pickle.load(open("prediction_model.sav", 'rb'))

def result(d):
    value=model._predict(d)
    if(value == 1):
        return "your test is positive "
    else:
        return "your test is negative "                                                                                                                         when I add these lines where my model make prediction on a particular data and it work fine when I run it on pycharm it dose not show any error and the same code crashes when I try to run it on android kivy launcher